# Объясните порядок вычисления

Tags: javascript

Вывожу в консоль такой код -`сonsole.log(++g + fun(g));`. В g число, а в fun `return g + g`. Как я понял выражение вызова функции имеет больший приоритет чем инкремент и сначала должно выполнится оно. Но g вычисляется уже увеличенной в fun(g), почему? Ведь инкрементирование должно быть после выражения вызова.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если я правильно понимаю, нужно учитывать не только приоритет операторов, но и ассоциативность. Приоритет можно воспринимать как «где подразумеваются круглые скобки», а ассоциативность — в каком порядке происходит вычисление.

Высший приритет не означает, что его связка будет выполнена всегда первой, где бы он ни стоял, вне зависимости от ассоциативности операторов с низшим приоритетом. Он означает, что результат этой связки станет новым операндом до того, как дело дойдёт до оператора низшего приоритета.

В MDN [русский перевод начала страницы о приоритете](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence) не такой полный, как [английский текст](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence), где добавлено уточнение:  операторы с высшим приоритетом становятся операндами для операторов с низшим приоритетом.

Оператор сложения имеет ассоциативность слева направо. Поэтому левое значение будет всё равно вычислено раньше функции. Приоритет вызова функции означает только, когда именно будет добавлен вызов. Например, если бы приоритет вызова функции был ниже, чем у сложения, вычисление производилось бы так: `((++g) + fun)(g)`. А при настоящих правилах оно производится так: `(++g) + (fun(g))`.

Порядок, насколько я понимаю, такой.

При префиксном инкременте:

1. `g` увеличивается.
2. `g` становится операндом.
3. `fun(g)` вызывается с увеличенным `g`.
4. Результат вызова становится операндом.
5. Сложение.

При cуффиксном инкременте:

1. `g` становится операндом.
2. `g` увеличивается.
3. `fun(g)` вызывается с увеличенным `g`.
4. Результат вызова становится операндом.
5. Сложение.

В обоих случаях функция получает уже увеличенное `g`. Разница лишь в значении левого операнда:

```js
'use strict';

function fun(arg) {
  console.log(arg);
  return arg + arg;
}

let g = 5;
console.log(g++ + fun(g));

g = 5;
console.log(++g + fun(g));
```

```
6
17
6
18
```

Answer (score 3):

Зависит от синтаксиса:

`++g` - инкрементируется до выполнения текущего выражения.

`g++` - после выполнения.

Пример:

```
var x = 1;
var y = x++; // y равно 1, x равно 2
var z = ++x; // z равно 3, x равно 3
```

Comment: Ок, но как это влияет на то, что я написал? Как я понимаю fun(g) должен выполнится еще до какого то ни было инкремента.

Comment: Меня сам порядок интересует. Если в g допустим 5, то fun(g) должно вернуть 10, а потом ++g вернет 6 и соответственно дальше 6+10.

Comment: Но так не получается, значит я что-то не понимаю.. Прошу объяснить.

Comment: Если плюсы до - то сначала инкремент, потом всё остальное. Если после, то сначала все остальное, а после этого инкремент. Написано же.

Comment: Напишите у себя инкремент по-другому (g++) и сравните.

Comment: В том-то и  дело, что ничего не изменилось. g++ возвращает не измененное значение, но fun(g) все также принимает уже инкрементированное значение.

Comment: Тогда странно. Какая-то очередная странная особенность яваскрипта.

Answer (score 2):

В подтверждение слов @Эникейщик привожу несколько примеров.
В первых двух приоритета выполнения функции нет, так порядок выполнения следующий:

- сначала операции с g в первом слагаемом (в случае g++ инкремент выполняется после сложения, но перед передачей значения в функцию),
- потом вычисление функции,
- сложение

А вот в 3 и 4 примерах приоритет становится очевидным.

```js
var g = 1;

function fn(g) {
  console.log(`input parameter: ${g}`);
  return g + g;
}

console.log(++g + fn(g));

g = 1;

console.log(g++ + fn(g));

// а вот в примерах ниже уже работает приоритет function
g = 1;

console.log(fn(++g));

g = 1;

console.log(fn(g++));
```

Comment: Вот мне и непонятно почему в первых двух у выражения вызова функции нет приоритета. В книге по JS написано  "Следует учитывать, что выражения вызова и обращения к свойству имеют более высокий приоритет, чем любой из операторов в таблице 4.1" т.е у инкремента ниже приоритет.

Comment: Инкремент - это оператор, который осуществляет неявным образом операцию присваивания. Т.е. можно провести аналогию с функцией. В зависимости от ++g или g++ поведение этой "функции" отличается. И отличается в том, какое значение g будет передано оператору сложения. Но к моменту когда вызывается функция значение g уже будет изменено.

Comment: Мне не понятно, почему оно уже будет изменено к моменту вызова функции, Ведь у вызова функции приоритет выше чем у инкремента. А значит сначала должна выполнится функция с не инкрементированой g.  Т.е  сначала fun(g), потом g++ или ++g ( не важно ), а уже потом сложение  получившихся значений.

Comment: Я вижу, что это не так работает и хочу понять почему.

Comment: Надеюсь моя логика Вам понятна, вроде бы подробно объяснил.

Answer (score 0):

Потому что порядок вычисления подвыражений в JavaScript всегда выполняется слева направо. Вычисление подвыражений производится перед выполнением всего выражения, а так как оператор ++ имеет побочный эффект, то происходит увеличение его операнда на 1, а затем это значение используется для выполнения выражения.